# Select2 library not working inside VueJs component

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vite, inertiajs

I have a Laravel 10, InertiaJs 1.0 project. I created this Vuejs component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <select class="form-control" :id="id" :name="name" :disabled="disabled" :required="required"></select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'select2/dist/js/select2.full';
import 'select2/dist/css/select2.min.css'
export default {
  name: 'Select2',
  data() {
    return {
      select2: null
    };
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  props: {
    modelValue: [String, Array], // previously was `value: String`
    id: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    placeholder: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    options: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
    disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    required: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    settings: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {}
    },
  },
  watch: {
    options: {
      handler(val) {
        this.setOption(val);
      },
      deep: true
    },
    modelValue: {
      handler(val) {
        this.setValue(val);
      },
      deep: true
    },
  },
  methods: {
    setOption(val = []) {
      this.select2.empty();
      this.select2.select2({
        placeholder: this.placeholder,
        ...this.settings,
        data: val
      });
      this.setValue(this.modelValue);
    },
    setValue(val) {
      if (val instanceof Array) {
        this.select2.val([...val]);
      } else {
        this.select2.val([val]);
      }
      this.select2.trigger('change');
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.select2 = $(this.$el)
      .find('select')
      .select2({
        placeholder: this.placeholder,
        ...this.settings,
        data: this.options
      })
      .on('select2:select select2:unselect', ev => {
        this.$emit('update:modelValue', this.select2.val());
        this.$emit('select', ev['params']['data']);
      });
    this.setValue(this.modelValue);
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    this.select2.select2('destroy');
  }
};
</script>
```

and installed both JQuey and select2 using npm but when I use Select2 component inside a page
it give me this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.select2 is null
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).find(...).select2 is not a function
```

I know it is because of using Vite but I don't know how to fix it.

I also removed this lines from component:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'select2/dist/js/select2.full';
import 'select2/dist/css/select2.min.css'
```

and used it inside bootstrap.js like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = window.$ = $;

import select2 from 'select2';
window.select2 = select2;
```

but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Why using Jquery with vuejs. I recommand you to switch to something more native with vue like primevue:

https://primevue.org/dropdown/

There are tons of component libraries that work directly with Vue.

Comment: The best offer! Thank you for saving my day